# Is limiting/cutting password-length without notice insecure?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

I have encountered that our linux system cuts the length of every password to a certain length, after that length every additional character seems to be ignored.

Does this make our linux system more succeptible to a brute force dictionary attack? Also the length of a password at work isn't 100% a secret, as you will hear someone typing either shortly or quite long. Could someone with malicious intent use this to crack a long password with a dictionary attack of common words, by assuming all complicated characters are at the end?

Comment: The tale of passwords being truncated to X characters makes me think that the affected systems use a really old and insecure password hashing system. I really hope to be wrong though, because it's quite worrying to see such old and extremely insecure technology still being used.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely - and "without notice" is pretty bad here.

Your example (a construction that starts with a word and has more complicated bits at the end) is a good one.  XKCD's "[correct horse battery staple](https://xkcd.com/936/)" would also be reduced to just the first word, making the space trivial to brute-force.

If a security-savvy user is aware of this restriction, they could choose a different password construction, but that's a really terrible thing to ask users to do.  An security-savvy user who is *unaware* of this restriction could easily end up with equivalent security to your average `hunter2` password.